# How to restrict users to fetch datalike videos from database and display only one video per day

Tags: php, date

I was trying to make a program in PHP for a project in school where I have to restrict users to fetch videos from a video library unlimited times. We need to give them one video per day per user according to their date of joining and last up to 100 days only. We tried it in PHP with the `strtotime()` function, but were not able the right way to make one such.

Comment: Use [DateTime](http://php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php) and [DateTime::diff](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.diff.php)

Comment: Your question may need more context before any one can provide an actual code example. Assuming your users are logged in, you need to store the videos they view on your database with the corresponding date it was viewed. And create a checker that queries the video/s viewed on the same day the user is attempting to view a new video. If you have users that are not logged in, you may need to rely on their IP to validate their views.